Why is the back EMF subtracted from total voltage instead of the voltage across the coil component?
I understand all of this question except for the very end. It is from a test I was looking at from a couple of years ago.

A coil consists of 150 turns of wire and has a total resistance of 200 Ohm. It is connected in series with a 120 V d.c. power supply and a parallel combination of a 200 Ohm and a 50 ohm resistor.


The d.c. supply is then replaced with an a.c. supply. It takes 3 ms for the magnetic flux cutting the coil to increase by 4.5×10–4Wb.


The average voltage of the a.c. supply during this time period is 120 V. Calculate (i) the average emf induced in the coil during the 3 ms time period

E=dΦ/dt
E=0.15(V)
0.15×150=22.5V
All of this so far makes sense to me and I understand this to be the voltage generated in the coil as a result of Faraday's law of electromagnetic induction
What I don't get is in the next part the answer says to use the total minus this induced EMF.
Why is this the voltage we shpuld use in order to find the average current?
(ii) the average current in the coil during this period.
Ecoil=97.5(V)
I=97.5/240=0.406A
Can someone please help and clear this up for me?
